# Setting relation between multiple tables in PostgreSQL w/Gorm using a foreignKey

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, go-gorm

So I have two different tables:

```
type Service struct {
 gorm.Model
 UserID     string `gorm:"type:uuid"`
 Name       string
}

type Artifact struct {
 gorm.Model
 UserID   string `gorm:"type:uuid"`
}
```

There are other tables similar to Artifact but the main idea is that I want to make the relation so if I delete a service, it'll delete all of the entries in the related tables.

I tried adding a foreignKey to the Service table as such:

```
type Service struct {
 gorm.Model
 UserID     string `gorm:"type:uuid"`
 Name       string

 Artifacts Artifacts `gorm:"foreignKey:UserID"`
}
```

But this makes the UserID go from uuid type to bigint. How can I make sure the type remains as uuid?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define a relationship where deleting a Service instance also deletes related entries in other tables (e.g., Artifact, etc), you need to define the foreign key relationships and configure the **cascading delete** behavior.

Your code should be something like this:

```
type Service struct {
 gorm.Model
 UserID     string `gorm:"type:uuid"`
 Name       string

 Artifacts []Artifact `gorm:"foreignkey:UserID;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}
```

To preserve the UserID type to uuid you can explicitly define it while creating the foreign key.

```
type Service struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID     string `gorm:"type:uuid"`
    Name       string

    Artifacts []Artifact `gorm:"foreignKey:UserID;references:UserID;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;type:uuid"`
}
```

Comment: The type remained as uuid so that works. What doesn't work now is when I try to add into the service I get a `failed to encode args[14]: unable to encode main.Artifacts{} into binary format for uuid (OID 2950): cannot find encode plan` . When I'm adding into the table I use a string in place of uuid, it was working without the foreign key. Should I be changing something else when calling DB.Create()?

Comment: This is a very specific error which is very hard to resolve without looking at the codebase.The error you're encountering suggests an issue with encoding related to the Artifacts association. When working with associations in GORM, you need to make sure that you're handling them correctly when creating or updating records.